# Would it been seen negatively if a part of a Qualification's name was omitted?

Tags: resume

One of my Qualification is titled Bachelor of Information Technology (Computer Games). in comparison to a normal Bachelor of Information Technology it's the exact same having the exact same Core Subjects that must be taken and passed. the difference in them is that with the Computer Games one, with the Electives (Subjects i must choose) there are 2 kinds, Electives and Games Electives with the latter only having a pool of subjects related only to Games, the former is any subject including those from the Games Electives Pool.

Despite explaining this my parents still complain saying that no employer will hire someone who did Computer Games in University. i have had 2 previous jobs and at the time listed that my Bachelor was in Computer Games. i believe my first job was very supportive of this because there was also a couple of gamers in the team (even during our personal work period at the end of the week one of them would be working on Drones and another would be showing off their Kickstarter Prizes like a mini projector, or a pen that drew in plastic) while my second job was the opposite going so far as to prevent me from learning anything outside what was required of work (ie. other programming languages, foreign cultures, even how to create a passive income) and i belive they only accepted my qualification as a trade off to the PHP Skills they would acquire from me.

Before my first job i was unemployed for half a year so i am unsure if employers back then or currently are seeing the Computer Games part of my Qualification and not even give me a second thought. that said since both the regular Bachelor of Information Technology and Computer Games one are more or less the exact same and that i recall in an interview when i forgot to bring my Bachelor one of my interviewers saying they could check up on it themselves, i am wondering that if i removed the Computer Games part of my Qualification would it be seen as dishonest and thus i would be seen negatively?

Comment: "*foreign cultures, even how to create a passive income*" Why on earth would you think this is something you should be able to do while you're being paid to *work*?

Comment: "no employer will hire someone who did Computer Games in University" - really? I would think the ability to program computer games is a general advantage.

Comment: @Brandin Presumably the issue is one of maturity and the possibility that OP is only applying for a non-videogame job to make ends meet and will leave the second he gets his "dream job". Regardless, it's not relevant to the actual question asked here.

Comment: So basically, your degree is officially "Bachelor of Information Technology in Computer Games", and you would like to simply write "Bachelor of Information Technology" on your CV instead?

Comment: @Lilienthal when there was work for me to go onto i focused on my work but if it was during my break or when there was no work (ie. there was no more tasks left for me) i would then do self improvement to keep myself occupied. it was ok in my first job so i assumed it was ok in my second but not only could i not do that during my break i couldn't improve any other programming skills. i lost out on so much time i could have been learning C# then but instead i had to sit around and wait for my supervisor to fine another website that haddn't been done because i didn't have access

Comment: @Lilienthal there's no opportunities for me to get a computer games job where i live at the moment so i have to apply for non games jobs but my parents have never been supportive of my dream but i can not confirm or deny their remark since i can only assume that my first job was ok with it while my second job wasn't but my PHP Skills were to good to pass up

Comment: @Brandin that is correct. as i pointed out in one interview i had when i forgot my Bachelor Certificate the interviewer said they could check up on it meaning that employers seems to have access to something that tells them what qualifications i do have so i'm not sure if would be dishonest for me to leave it out even though the subjects i would have to have passed are the exact same

Comment: Self-improvement that's work-related is fine in most jobs during downtime. If you have no such downtime then it follows that you're expected to be productive instead. This will vary by job and in many programming jobs you'll be learning as you go when working with new technologies. But you're not going to get away with educating yourself about personal finance in a programming job.

Comment: If you're out of work then you need to be asking your manager what you should be doing instead. If he can't give you *anything* and you can't find any other team to help out on you should be allowed to work on proof-of-concept projects or developing job-related skills. I can't think of many who'll actually do so but your manager *can* tell you not to do any of that and sit there staring at a blank wall instead. Anyway, all of this as well as the viability of your bachelor is irrelevant to the question. Bring this up in [chat] if you want to discuss it.

Comment: It's absolutely fine to say you have a Bachelor of Information Technology and I would recommend doing it.

Comment: @Memor-X My parents didn't support me contributing hours upon hours to open-source MMO game projects. They thought video games were a waste of time. That experience I learned led to me landing a non-video game programming position that far exceeds my parents' income when they worked. *Their perspectives have changed.* Your degree doesn't always matter when applying for a job. What matters is that you can exhibit knowledge in the area required to fulfill the job. If a company is hiring based on degree alone, then you probably don't want to work there anyways.

Answer (score 5):

I have exactly the same qualification title as yourself and personally I don't feel it has been a disadvantage. I have worked a year in games development for a year and afterwards nearly 7 years in other industries.

After deciding to move away from the games industry, I made sure I tailored every application to the role (which possibly does underplay the games experience) but this is something you should do for any application.

I never had any feedback from an employer saying that the games degree was a problem and if we did talk about my course I answered honestly. The games modules on my course contained many elements useful in general (mathematics, graphics, scripting, etc etc) that the general degree didn't contain so you should be prepared also to present these as an advantage.

In short I would try to embrace your course title not be seen to be ashamed of it, even hiding something by omission can be taken negatively and get you off on the wrong foot.